# How to retrieve values from a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get variable data "$b ,$d, $f,$h" from database and then calculate it. Here is my example:

```
    <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="root";
    $db_name="cbrteh"

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $b= mysql_query("SELECT bobot FROM atribut where id= 1"); 
    ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($b));
    $row["bobot"];
    $d= mysql_query("SELECT bobot FROM atribut where id= 2"); 
    ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($d));
     $row["bobot"];
    $f= mysql_query("SELECT bobot FROM atribut where id= 3"); 
    ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($f));
    $row["bobot"];
    $h= mysql_query("SELECT bobot FROM atribut where id= 4"); 
    ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($h));
    $row["bobot"];
    $calc = $b+$d+$f+$h;
    echo $calc;
<?
```

The values in the database are 50,50,50,50 but the result is 22. Why is this?

Comment: Both the code and the question are an unreadable mess. Indent your code, spellcheck your text, and describe what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please format your code...

Comment: you're not assigning the values into your variables

Answer (score 1):

The line below every query string is wrong

```
($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($b));
    $row["bobot"];
```

Because you are not storing the result anywhere.The correct way to get the values should be:

```
if(count($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($b))>0)$_b=$res[0]['bobot'];
```

(if returning result has at least one row, return the value to `$_b` variable)

Mind that `$b` is being used to store the query result, not the value you get from it.

Then you sum the results like this:
`$calc = $_b+$_d+$_f+$_h;`  and that's all.

Comment: You can drop the `>0` if the conditional, since the non-zero result will be cast to boolean anyway. Also, I'd assign `$_b` using the ternary form, so that it takes a value even if no results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could do all the work in your database:

```
$query = mysql_query(
    "SELECT SUM(bobot) AS summation FROM atribut where id IN (1,2,3,4)"
);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$calc = $row['summation'];
```

I've removed the unnecessary brackets around the assignment to `$row`, and of course I've replaced four separate lookups with just one. Since I've used the grouping function `SUM`, I have aliased it as `summation` so it is easy to retrieve from the row.