# php mysql get variable data from database and calculate

Tags: php, mysql

hello fellow overflower i have problem iwant to get variable data "$b ,$d, $f,$h" from database and then calculate it 
 here my example

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="root";
    $db_name="cbrteh"

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $b= mysql_query("SELECT bobot FROM atribut where id= 1"); 
    ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($b));
    $row["bobot"];
    $d= mysql_query("SELECT bobot FROM atribut where id= 2"); 
    ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($d));
     $row["bobot"];
    $f= mysql_query("SELECT bobot FROM atribut where id= 3"); 
    ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($f));
    $row["bobot"];
    $h= mysql_query("SELECT bobot FROM atribut where id= 4"); 
    ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($h));
    $row["bobot"];
    $calc = $b+$d+$f+$h;
    echo $calc;
```

is my script right 
the value on database are 50,50,50,50 so the value must be 200
 but the value i got from echo $calc; is 22

Comment: You have an `$row4` not used in your code

Comment: Unclear what you're asking and WHY your're asking it!

Comment: Why do you have so many queries?

Comment: SELECT SUM(bobot) FROM atribu WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve values from a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351250/how-to-retrieve-values-from-a-database)

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate of your earlier identical question. Please don't ask questions twice, as it just wastes people's time through duplicated effort. Bear in mind that if you do this a lot, the resultant and deserved downvotes may trigger a temporary question ban on your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$b= mysql_query("SELECT bobot FROM atribut where id= 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($b);
$b   = $row[0]; 
$d= mysql_query("SELECT bobot FROM atribut where id= 2");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($d);
$d   = $row[0];
[...] // repeat for $f and $h
$calc = $b + $d + $f + $h;
echo($calc);
```

Or, maybe used any more appropriate code :

```
$b= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(bobot) as calc FROM atribut WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($b);
$calc = $row[0];
echo($calc);
```

Comment: This cannot be to most appropriate way of solving this problem - whatever this problem is!

Answer (score 1):

You should store the values of the querys in variables and then sum them.

```
$b = $row["bobot"];
```

And so on....