# How can i get result from price*quantity?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get a automatic calculation from quantity*price
so, I am a newbie.

Check Screenshot:
[image]

```
<?php

$result_order= $this->db->where('userID',$this->session->userdata('IDname'))->get('order')->result();
//print_r($result_order);


foreach ($result_order as $row => $item) {
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td>'.$item->foodID.'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$item->foodname.'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$item->cost.'</td>';
    /*echo'<td width="55"><input class="qty_input" type="number" name="item_qty" min="1" max="10"</td>'; */
echo'<td width="55"><input type="number" name="items_qty[<?php echo $row; ?>]" id="item<?php echo $row; ?>_qty"  min="1" max="10"></td>'; 
echo'<td> '.$item->cost.'*$item_qty  </td>';
echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
echo'</tr>  ';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Where are you stuck at doing so?

Comment: I even know how to copy and post on this, so i save a picture and post on to this...so pls check T T

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Comment: i can't post with text.. i don't know sorry T T

Comment: i stuck with lines 69 and 70 pls help me

Comment: check this link if it helps u to calcu
---------- http://stackoverflow.com/a/21351801/6060115

Comment: So, i need to declare a variable? and how can i declare pls give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try after change

```
echo'<td> '.$item->cost.'*$item_qty  </td>';
```

To

```
echo'<td> '.$item->cost*$item_qty.'  </td>';
```

And make sure both are integer

Comment: Thank you, but i get an error when i add a value is it right?>>>

echo'<td width="55"><input type="number" name="items_qty" id="item<?php echo $row; ?>_qty" value="<?php echo $item['qty']; ?>" min="1" max="10"></td>';